# navigationBar appear under statusBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I asked this question but not correctly. I created NavigationVC controller:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface NavigationVC : UINavigationController

- (void)setTitleText:(NSString *)title calendar:(BOOL)calendar moveToLeft:(BOOL)left;
 //this method for create title of navigationitem that I then use in all ViewControllers

@end
```

In NavigationVC.m I have:

```
@implementation NavigationVC

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
  self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
  if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
  return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
   [self.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backGroundLayer.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

Image backGoundLayer.png have resolution 320x44 and I have backGround@2x.png with 640x88

I created viewcontroller BaseVC, that inherited from UIViewController, and other viewcontrollers inherited from BaseVC.

I created in storyboard my nibs

[image]

And my problem next:

[image]

first background image appear under statusBar but you can see that other background image appear underneath of statusBar. I try in storyboard change statusBar to black, but it not helped me. I try write method

```
[self.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backGroundLayer.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

 In viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear in NavigationVC, but it not helped too.
```

And I have second problem.
 I create button in viewcontroller and when it touched I push next view. I add title programmatically to first view and to second. When I touch button I see in moment title of second view (and this title above than it must be, I think that background appear without statusBar), then title of second view disappear and I see empty navigationBar. When I click backButton and go to first view I see on first view navigationBar title of second view. What the problem?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking, but re: the status bar colour, you should be able to set it from the 'Simulated Metrics' section of Interface Builder (click on the VC and it'll be the top panel on the right)

Comment: I add picture of my problem, sorry I forgot add it in beginning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is feature of iOS 6, by default status bar takes color of navigation bar. You can change this behaviour by changing status bar style on target summary page.

Answer (score 1):

There is no image behind the status bar, in iOS 6 the status will take over the color of the navigationbar.

If you change the statusbar style in the `info.plist` to `Opaque black style` it will stay black.